# How to detect JRE 8 is intslled or not via wix bootstrapping

Tags: java, c#, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7

I am using wix bootstrapping to install Java runtime. but I am not able to detect the JRE. My code is as below. Installer will always install JRE (even it is pre installed). but will not uninstall.

It seems like my Detect condition is wrong. But I am not able to find the correct method. Please help

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?define Logo = "$(var.ProjectDir)\Resource\app.ico" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <Bundle Name="MY Installer" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="ABCD" UpgradeCode="00f3b9ff-f82b-4a06-8ab1-d96de8ade69c"
          IconSourceFile="$(var.Logo)">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        SuppressOptionsUI ="yes"
        SuppressRepair="yes"
        LicenseUrl=""
        LogoFile="$(var.Logo)" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <util:RegistrySearch
      Id="Java8FamilyVersion"
      Root="HKLM"
      Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
      Value="Java7FamilyVersion"
      Variable="Java8FamilyVersion" />

    <util:RegistrySearch
      Root="HKLM"
      Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\[Java8FamilyVersion]\MSI"
      Value="PRODUCTVERSION"
      Variable="JavaProductVersion"
      After="Java8FamilyVersion"
      Condition="Java8FamilyVersion" />

    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="Java8Runtime"
                  DisplayName="Java Runtime Version 8"
                  Cache="no"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Vital="yes"
                  Permanent="no"
                  Name="Redist\jre-8u271-windows-x64.exe"
                  SourceFile="..\..\Common\Java\jre-8u271-windows-x64.exe"
                  InstallCondition="NOT (JavaProductVersion &gt;v8.0.2710.9)"
                  DetectCondition="Java8FamilyVersion AND (JavaProductVersion &gt;=v8.0.2710.9)" 
                  InstallCommand="/s INSTALL_SILENT=Enable"/>

      
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

'''

Comment: It looks like you may be installing to a 64-bit system. Are you aware of the 64-bit registry redirection that happens when you're running a 32-bit process like the bootstrapper?

Comment: @Doc, Yes I am installing to a 64 bit system. I actually build the installer as 64 bit. "Are you aware of the 64-bit registry redirection that happens when you're running a 32-bit process like the bootstrapper? " - This item actually I am not aware. Can you please help me with some link to get more information about this

Comment: open up your registry and take note that you have HKLM/Software/WOW6432Node hive on your 64-bit machine. Have your code look there and see if it starts working. If so that's your issue.

From there do some googling and you'll discover how to fix it.

Comment: @Doc, Thanks for the information. I can see "HKLM/Software/WOW6432Node" this path in my PC. But only a "JavaUpdatePolicy" is there. 

Also I can see "HKLM/Software/JavaSoft/Java Plug-in"  and "HKLM/Software/JavaSoft/Java Runtime" folders. Inside that I am not able to find any file that shows the current version of Java

Comment: how about manually creating the registry keys and data there to see if your bootstrapper is indeed reading the 32-bit key? This gist of my comment is which registry hive is it reading? This is a known dev issue when reading from the registry on 64-bit systems.